# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'mss'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having this error

```
Severity: Warning  --> mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'mss'@'localhost'
```

I'm using codeIgniter and I'm configuring the database this way:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cms';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;

$this->load->database($config);
```

I don't get where he's getting the mss username. At first I had mss in this config file but I changed to root

Comment: check if your login and password are correct

Comment: the username root has a blank password

Comment: if you use root , what is mss??

Comment: it was the first username I gave before root, but I don't know where the hell is getting this mss now.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible answer to your question is that you haven't uploaded the file correctly.

Check using an SSH connection that the file really has changed. If not, then you have to check your editor/IDE to see if it isn't your configuration that is incorrect and you might be uploading the files in the wrong place.